# handleSubmit works in Javascript but not in Typescript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to handle form submission in react with events using an external function and I get this error message in Typescript React.

```
Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
```

Here's the code :

```
function Form() {
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('You clicked submit.');
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

This works fine in regular javascript or as a callback function inside `onClick()`. However in Typescript, it poses a problem. How do I resolve this?

Comment: The TypeScript config has an option to allow or disallow implicit `any` types.  Are you disallowing them?  Do you want to allow them?  Do you want to explicitly specify the `any` type for your variable?  Something else?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to bind the `onSubmit` function and define the type of the event parameter with [React.SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), to do so follow the code snippet below:

```
function Form() {
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('You clicked submit.');
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

for more details, check please this great resource  [react-typescript-cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events/).